# org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext

Tags: jboss7.x, slf4j, logback

I get the following error when i use logback in maven (m2e).Environment: JBOSS 7.1.1,maven,eclipse. But it work fine if i just run individually as main class. I couldn't figure out why i am getting this error, can anyone help me troubleshooting this issue and find a solution for it.

## Error

```
17:24:23,675 ERROR [stderr] java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext 

17:24:23,681 ERROR [stderr] at com.zreflect.emyed.whiteboard.pubsub.EventLoggerAsync.logStart(EventLoggerAsync.java:116) 

17:24:23,683 ERROR [stderr] at com.zreflect.emyed.whiteboard.pubsub.EventLoggerAsync.onDisconnect(EventLoggerAsync.java:62) 

17:24:23,684 ERROR [stderr] at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.onDisconnect(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:817) 

17:24:23,686 ERROR [stderr] at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.notifyListeners(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:761) 

17:24:23,688 ERROR [stderr] at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.notifyListeners(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:742) 

17:24:23,690 ERROR [stderr] at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.cancelled(AsynchronousProcessor.java:601) 

17:24:23,691 ERROR [stderr] at org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport.cancelled(BlockingIOCometSupport.java:172) 

17:24:23,693 ERROR [stderr] at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor$1.run(AsynchronousProcessor.java:119) 

17:24:23,694 ERROR [stderr] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) 

17:24:23,696 ERROR [stderr] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) 

17:24:23,698 ERROR [stderr] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) 

17:24:23,699 ERROR [stderr] at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) 

17:24:23,703 ERROR [stderr] at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) 

17:24:23,707 ERROR [stderr] at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204) 

17:24:23,715 ERROR [stderr] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) 

17:24:23,716 ERROR [stderr] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) 

17:24:23,718 ERROR [stderr] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Where does JBoss AS 7 come in here too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that `com.zreflect.emyed.whiteboard.pubsub.EventLoggerAsync` class is expecting a `ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext`, instead it obtains a `org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory`. This usually occurs when some code tries to cast the return value of `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory` and slf4j is bound to the NOP implementation because no slf4j binding was available on the class path. This is usually accompanied by [an error message](http://slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder).

Comment: I have the following files in the WEB-INF/lib. But still get the error. 

slf4j-api-1.7.3.jar,logback-classic-1.0.10.jar,logback-core-1.0.10.jar

Comment: Where is com.zreflect.emyed.whiteboard.pubsub.EventLoggerAsync located?

Comment: it is located in WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: I've a similar problem when I run 'sbt test', but if I run 'sbt testOnly TestX' everything is ok. How can I try to solve/understand this error? @Ceki

Answer (score 0):

For info, if it can help, I had the same issue:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory cannot be cast to class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
```

with JBoss Wildfly 7.4 when using SLF4J 2.0.3 (logback 1.3.4) and this was due to https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-548 and the wrong ClassLoader in use.
Updating to SLF4J 2.0.4 solves this NOPLogger issue