# org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger

Tags: java, scala, logging, slf4j, logback

I've seen some questions very similar to this one ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483309/org-slf4j-helpers-noploggerfactory-cannot-be-cast-to-ch-qos-logback-classic-logg)), but none of them received a good answer, or at least one that explained or solved this problem

I was able to create a very small project (basically 2 Scala classes - each with a logger - and 2 test classes) with a similar structure to my real project where I found the problem. The example is available here: [project example](https://bitbucket.org/pedrorijo91/logger-exp)

The problem happens when I run `sbt test`, resulting in the following error:

```
{14:43:41} (#47) ~/Desktop/logger-exp/log-exp@pedrorijo(master) $ sbt test
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/pedrorijo/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/pedrorijo/Desktop/git/scala/logger-exp/log-exp/project
[info] Set current project to log-exp (in build file:/Users/pedrorijo/Desktop/git/scala/logger-exp/log-exp/)
[info] HelloTest:
[info] Exception encountered when attempting to run a suite with class name: HelloTest *** ABORTED ***
[info]   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
[info]   at HelloTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(HelloTest.scala:8)
[info]   at HelloTest$$anonfun$1.apply(HelloTest.scala:8)
[info]   at HelloTest$$anonfun$1.apply(HelloTest.scala:8)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
[info]   at org.scalatest.FunSuiteLike$$anon$1.apply(FunSuiteLike.scala:166)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1122)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLogger cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
[info]   at com.example.Hello$.<init>(Hello.scala:8)
[info]   at com.example.Hello$.<clinit>(Hello.scala)
[info]   at HelloTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(HelloTest.scala:8)
[info]   at HelloTest$$anonfun$1.apply(HelloTest.scala:8)
[info]   at HelloTest$$anonfun$1.apply(HelloTest.scala:8)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
[info]   ...
SLF4J: The following set of substitute loggers may have been accessed
SLF4J: during the initialization phase. Logging calls during this
SLF4J: phase were not honored. However, subsequent logging calls to these
SLF4J: loggers will work as normally expected.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#substituteLogger
SLF4J: com.example.Hello$
14:43:52.846 [pool-6-thread-4-ScalaTest-running-WorldTest] INFO  com.example.World$ - LOGGING
[info] WorldTest:
[info] - test
[info] Run completed in 456 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 1
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 SUITE ABORTED ***
[error] Error during tests:
[error]     HelloTest
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 2, 2015 2:43:52 PM
```

but if I run each of the tests individually through:

`sbt "testOnly HelloTest"` and `sbt "testOnly WorlTest"` I get no error.

As far as I've seen this is not just a Scala issue, it seems that in Java is also possible to happen. Furthermore, I've read that during initialization the loggers are substituted by a  [Substitute Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#substituteLogger).

But I can't understand:

1. why it only happens in tests, and when running both tests?
2. why it happens?
3. how to debug/solve this problem?

> As I said before, I've created a repository with a working example (working, meaning with the error happening) here: [project example](https://bitbucket.org/pedrorijo91/logger-exp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the problem was in the following statement:

`val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(X.getClass).asInstanceOf[Logger]`

I found this way of getting a Logger somewhere, so I never though the problem could be this line. The final method is unnecessary and it's the error cause. To stop getting the described error I've removed the forced cast, replacing the previous expression by:

`val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(X.getClass)`